# Can you use Azure Cloud Shell to cd into a data lake store?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Let's say you have a data lake store named **address** located at adl://address.azuredatalakestore.net/. Can you use Azure Cloud Shell to cd into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not "cd" into a data lake store. You'll need to use other commands to connect to and manipulate the data stored in Azure Data Lake.

Comment: I have a bunch of directories. Each contains a .csv file. I want to loop over the folders and insert each one into a table in sql server (also on azure). I don't want to do this by pulling each file down locally.

Comment: @KingHenryV Ok, please try something, then ask another question on SO to help you when you get stuck or have questions.

Comment: Oh, my only question is this. Is Powershell a dead-end for what I want, and should I switch to data factory instead? It's more of a "what approach should I take" than "how do I do this technical thing."

Comment: PowerShell as a scripting environment is possible to do pretty much anything. You'll need to try something, then ask a specific question about what you're trying to do. Also, don't use a Comment to post the question either.